# Using IF in an ArrayFormula in Google Sheets to check values in each column and not just a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to use `ARRAYFORMULA()` in Google Sheets to automatically apply a formula whenever a new row is entered. What I want is to check if today falls between two dates (a start and end date) or not. My formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A), "", if(and(today() >= B2, today() <= D2), "On Leave", "Available")))
```

That formula keeps checking against B2 and D2 for all rows inserted, so I tried this:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A), "", if(and(today() >= B2:B, today() <= D2:D), "On Leave", "Available")))
```

This second formula checks against all the values in column B and column D for every row, as against checking the respective value in column B and column D for that particular row e.g. row 3: B3, D3; row 4: B4, D4 etc.

Is there anyway I can get my desired behaviour? I've attached a screenshot of my sheet.

[image: Google Sheet Screenshot]

With the correct formula, Bruce Lee would not be on leave.

Answer (score 1):

In an array formula, you need to use * (multiply) instead of AND to get the desired behaviour:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A), "", if((today() >= B2:B)*( today() <= D2:D), "On Leave", "Available")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Any idea how to achieve an OR?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, exactly the same idea but use + instead of OR. BTW it's fine in an if statement as above, but have to be more careful generally because the + evaluation may give 2, 3 etc. if more than one condition is satisfied.